# bash: insert character at specified position in file

Tags: text-processing

Lets say I have following file

```
word1          something       blabla
anotherword    somethingelse   asdf
yetanother     else            123
```

For each line, I need to put a comment infront of the second column, which always starts at position 15 (that is, to insert `#` at position 15). How can I do it?

Comment: You should be careful about specifying things in terms of character position. You're bound to run into trouble with non-ASCII encoded files this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming GNU `sed` or compatible for its `-r` option¹

```
sed -r -e 's/^.{15}/&#/' file
```

results in

```
word1          #something       blabla
anotherword    #somethingelse   asdf
yetanother     #else            123
```

---

<sup>¹ that's for extended regexp support. Most other `sed`s support `-E` for that now (including GNU `sed` since version 4.2 though it wasn't documented until 4.3, released long after this answer was initially written) as that's what is now in the 2023 edition of the POSIX standard. Without `-E`/`-r`, you'd use `\{...\}` instead of `{...}`.</sup>

Comment: Does this also work in the Windows command prompt?

Comment: @0x499602D2 What do you mean the "Windows command prompt"? `sed` is a *nix tool. Are you talking about Cygwin?

Comment: @JosephR. Yes I am

Comment: @0x499602D2, "Windows command prompt" is, AFAIK, `cmd`, not Cygwin.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution with `awk`:

```
awk '{$2="#"$2;print $0}' your_file
```

This will add `#` to the start of the second (space-separated) column regardless of which position it occurs at.

Comment: Note that this collapses the pretty-printed tabular layout.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/./&X/15'
```

Replaces the 15<sup>th</sup> occurrence of a single character (`.`) with itself (`&`) followed by `X`. Beware that makes the second field wider by one character (offsets the start of the third and following fields by one character).

Answer (score 2):

To work with fixed-width fields, `perl`'s `pack`/`unpack` functions come handy:

```
$ cat file
word 1         something       blabla
anotherword    somethingelse123asdf
yetanother     else            123
$ perl -lne 'BEGIN {$format = "A15A16A*"}
             @f = unpack$format;
             $f[1] = "X$f[1]";
             print pack $format, @f' file
word 1         Xsomething      blabla
anotherword    Xsomethingelse12asdf
yetanother     Xelse           123
```

Where we insert `X` at the start of the second field. That second field remains 16 byte wide which in the case of the second line means it was truncated.

Answer (score 0):

The awk answer `awk '{$2="#"$2;print $0}'` is incorrect because it would reformat the white space and fails when one of the columns has a white space character.

```
word1          something       blabla
anotherword    somethingelse   asdf
yet another    else            123
```

for example would become:

```
word1 #something blabla
anotherword #somethingelse asdf
yet #another else 123
```

The correct awk answer is:
`awk '{print substr($0,1,15) "#" substr($0,16) }'`

Which gives the output:

```
word1          #something       blabla
anotherword    #somethingelse   asdf
yet another    #else            123
```